# gtkScale draws correctly in Glade, not in the final app

Tags: c, gtk3, glade, anjuta

I have several GtkScale widgets in my program (about 10 of them), each has its own GtkAdjustment declared (and assigned). In Glade, these Scales are drawn correctly - complete with the 'knobs' to adjust.

In the final application however, it seems as if the GtkAdjustment is not assigned, and the 'knobs' do not appear.

There was [a problem with Scales back in Glade 3.6](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=594372), but as this is version 3.18.3 this seems solved.

I've also checked the ui file, and the adjustment and scale definitions seem ok.

Any suggestions? There is no real code involved here... Here are the relevant sections of the UI file:

The Adjustment:

```
<object class="GtkAdjustment" id="mainwin_comp_cap_val_adj">
   <property name="upper">100</property>   
   <property name="value">10</property>
   <property name="step_increment">1</property>
   <property name="page_increment">10</property>
   <signal name="value-changed" handler="mainwin_comp_val_adj_value_changed" swapped="no"/>
</object>
```

And the corresponding Scale:

```
  <object class="GtkScale" id="mainwin_comp_cap_val_scale">
     <property name="visible">True</property>
     <property name="can_focus">True</property>
     <property name="adjustment">mainwin_comp_cap_val_adj</property>
     <property name="round_digits">1</property>
     <property name="draw_value">False</property>
  </object>
```

UPDATE:

For some reason, `Anjuta` stopped giving me the console output of my program (that's another issue though). This caused me to miss some warnings from the `gtkbuilder`. When debugging manually (without `Anjuta`), I get these warnings for each of the adjustments:

```
(linsmith:14942): Gtk-WARNING **: No object called: mainwin_comp_cap_val_adj
```

Again, I found some older references, but none with a solution (or even an explanation).

Comment: define them in your code if you can and delete them from glade

Comment: @user3238855 Yes, that would be a possibility, but I wonder if there is a known problem with the gtkbuilder system which causes this. After all, the ui files are there to simplify our work, aren't they? Doing everything manually would be admitting defeat...

Comment: In Python the adjustments have to be loaded from the builder separately from within the program code. Otherwise the application is not aware of their existence. Did you do something like this: https://github.com/tobias47n9e/innstereo/blob/master/innstereo/layer_properties.py#L36 ?

Comment: @tobias47n9e Yes, exactly. I have a table with all needed widgets to be pulled out of the UI, so I can access their properties, or modify their state. All Scales and Adjustments are in the table. I upvoted your comment, because there are very few examples on how to do it in Python nd they are always welcome (my program is in C).